# Учебник по русскому языку

Tags: общие-вопросы

Собственно хотелось бы освежить знания и пройти ЕГЭ в след. году. Старые учебники давно уже сданы, а покупать кипу новых не рентабельно (целесообразно), желательно один, но охватывающий сразу все классы. Что скажите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Домашний репетитор. Русский язык. Орфография. Пунктуация. Д.Э. Розенталь. И.Б. Голубь. Отличный учебник для подготовки ЕГЭ. Но параллельно к этому сдавайте онлайн ЕГЭ. Результат будет отличный (для тех, у кого есть достаточна крепкая база). Есть еще два учебника: Справочник-практикум. Орфография. Пунктуация. Д.Э.Розенталь. (Книга для специалистов). И, конечно же, Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Для ЕГЭ? Такие
 справочники? Да для теста даже учебника для 10-11 будет много.   
Тест в этом году примитивный.

Comment: Спасибо. А рекомендации к С части там имеются?

Comment: Примитивный? Я бы не сказал. Как всегда.

Comment: Ничего себе как всегда. Ничего себе как всегда! Ни синтаксиса, ни частей речи. 24 задания в тесте и сочинение.

Comment: Ни синтаксиса? А найти придаточное с последовательном подчинением? Это разве не синтаксис?